Creating tiptap node for custom HTML
I'd like to extend the tiptap editor with a custom field that would store HTML meant to be directly rendered on the frontend.
So currently the rendering part looks like this:
import { generateHTML } from "@tiptap/html";

const htmlContent = generateHTML(proseMirrorDocument, [
    StarterKit, 
    RelatedArticleNode,
    InArticleImageNode,
    //...
]);

In this list I define custom nodes for rendering elements. According to the previous example the new component would look something like this:
import { Node } from '@tiptap/core';

export const CustomHTMLNode = Node.create({
// ...
    renderHTML({ HTMLAttributes }) {
    // ...
    return ['div',{}, customHTML];

With the twist that I had to have my customHTML properly rendered on the frontend.
Basically the equivalent of
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: customHTML }} />

Any idea?

Achieving this with TipTap Node objects is not possible.
I ended up modifying the generated HTML with JSDOM. (Feel free to use the tool of your liking, cheerio, etc.), it's not so clean but at least simple from now on. With JSDOM, setting the innerHTML property of the element makes the content inside render like usual HTML.
// Load the HTML content into JSDOM
const dom = new JSDOM(htmlContent);

// Use the DOM API to select and update elements
const document = dom.window.document;
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.custom-html');

// Update the content of each selected div
divs.forEach(div => {
    div.innerHTML = div.textContent;
});

// Serialize the updated HTML back to a string
htmlContent = dom.serialize();

